# Proper design for multiple agents server

Tags: c#, .net, oop

(working on .net environment with C#)

We're writing a propriety server, that manages multiple data providing agents, here some pseudo-code so simplify the explanation:

```
class Server
{
  ServerManagementGUI server_gui; // a GUI to display all sort of Server related data

  MonitorAgent m_agnt;
  DataAgent    d_agnt;
  // will not be allocated or init at C'tor

  public write_data1();
  public write_data2();

  public get_data5();

  // etc
}

class Agent
{
// handles generic communication and threading issues

// a reference to Server is required to write 
// the data to it's private data structures. 
// please note that a delegate to one or more function will not suffice here.

Agent(Server server); 

}

class MonitorAgent : Agent
{
 // handles task spesific issues

}

class DataAgent : Agent
{
 // handles task spesific issues
}
```

the idea is that the agents collects the data asynchronously, and handles any communication and threading issues, and uses `Server`'s methods to fill it's data structures.
we're not sure that the above is a "good practice" design.

please let us know if you have any other idea or insights on our design.

***UPDATE:***
`Server` also have a GUI object to which it rights some info.
because the agents are those who actually generating the data (fetching it from the web, or getting it from hardware sensors) it must have direct access to methods of `ServerManagementGUI`. now, since each agent uses different method and properties of `Server` and `ServerManagementGUI` , we thought it would the most convenient to just pass a reference to the entire object.

Comment: There's a lot of different way of doing it, it all depends on the needs (which is not in the question). Why can't you use delegate? The agent could raise an event when something happens.

Comment: @the_lotus also, please let me know if its not clear enough yet.

Answer (score 0):

I would not be passing the Server reference directly to agents. What Agents need are not the actual server reference but an abstraction of the server let's say IServerContext. Let server object implements this interface for you and then during creation of agents you are able to inject a reference of IServerContext to the agents.
This helps you to have a low-couple communication contract between server and agents. So your agents are not dependent to the server implementation.
Also then it makes you able unit test the IServerContext simply and makes sure it provides required data and behaviour that different agents may need. 
Other benefit is you also then can use any IoC library to inject multiple different implementations of the context to different agents.